# Positive Series Convergence Test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

If $\sum a_n < \infty$ with $a_n \ge 0$ for all $n$, then is $\sum n a_n^2$ always convergent?

As I know, this is true if $\{a_n\}$ is a decreasing sequence with $a_n \ge 0$, because $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} na_n = 0$ by the Cauchy test and $a_n$ is bounded since $\sum a_n < \infty$. But, in this case, I don't know if $\{a_n\}$ is decreasing. Can I conclude that $\{a_n\}$ is a decreasing sequence if I know $\sum a_n < \infty$ with $a_n \ge 0$?

Would be very grateful if somebody could help me.

Comment: You can't conclude that $a_{n}$ is decreasing, but you can conclude that after a re-ordering $a_{n}$ is decreasing as $a_{n}$ converges to $0$.

Comment: But such reordering can significantly change the series $n \cdot a_n^2$.

Comment: Don't edit your question after an answer has been submitted, start a new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take, for example, series $$a_n = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},& \exists k \in \mathbb N\colon n = 4^k \\
0,& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Then $\sum a_n$ converges (it's non-zeros terms are $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \ldots$), but $4^k (a_{4^k})^2 = \frac{4^k}{(\sqrt{4^k})^2} = 1$, thus $n\cdot a_n^2 \not\to 0$, so $\sum n a_n^2$ diverges.